# Fake call to a web service in all cucumber tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

My Rails app makes a call to a web service.

I am using the **FakeWeb** gem to fake these calls in some tests by registering the URI like this:

```
FakeWeb.register_uri(:get, "http://webservice.com/param?value=a", :response => fake_response)
```

How can I set this fake registration for the entire test environment, as opposed to setting it up manually for each test ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a file in `spec/support/`, make a call to `register_uri` inside a `Before` block:

```
Before do
  FakeWeb.register_uri(:get, "http://webservice.com/param?value=a", :response => fake_response)
end
```

I use this trick to set up mock responses using [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock), and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, putting that in your spec/spec_helper.rb file will do the trick.  I haven't used FakeWeb, myself, but that's where you'd put any global initialization.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Tried your suggestion, no luck though.

Answer (score 1):

Take look at [VCR](https://github.com/myronmarston/vcr) rubygem.

It records your test suite's HTTP interactions and replays them during test run.